# SBT. How to run node.js package from task?

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying to run some `node.js` packages, while building scala project via `scala.system.process`. Let it be `yarn -v`.

```
lazy val ttt = taskKey[Unit]("Some task")
ttt := {
  import scala.sys.process._

  Seq("yarn.cmd", "-v").!
}
```

Output:

```
module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\08407540\IdeaProjects\test\node_modules\yarn\bin\yarn.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
```

---

But running from Main method is OK:
[image]

How to make `SBT` run packages, like from scala source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lazy val ttt = taskKey[Unit]("Some task")
ttt := {
  import scala.sys.process._

  Seq("cmd", "/c", "yarn", "-v").!
}
```

Works for me